# Writing function output to a text file?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that reads a set of names and numbers from one file, expresses the numbers as a ratio, then prints them out to the terminal. I would like to know how I could redirect the output of my functions to a separate file. I have an output file ready, but am unsure of how to redirect my functions' outputs to it.

I didn't include the functions themselves here, which work fine - just the calls.

```
int main(){
ifstream input;
ofstream output;
string inputname, outputname, name;
int num1, num2;
cout<<"Input file?\n";
cin>>inputname;
cout<<"Output file?\n";
inFile.open(inputname.c_str());
cin>>outputfile;
outFile.open(outputname.c_str());

while(!input.eof()&&!output.eof()){
    input>>name>>num1>>num2;
    lists (name);
    value (num1, num2);
}

input.close()
output.close()

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile since you're using an undefined (as far as what you've posted) variable: `outputfile`.

Comment: Checking output.eof() seems odd to me.

Comment: Other undefined variables: `inFile`, `outFile`.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Input/Output with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Example:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

As you see, it's *very* similar to how you're getting the data *from* fileA.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple undefined variables (Always test your program before posting!). And you're not checking for eof on the input file correctly. You need to test for eof right after a read operation to see if it succeeded.

```
int main(){

  cout << "Input file?\n";
  string inputname;
  cin >> inputname;
  ifstream input(inputname.c_str());
  if (!input) return 1; // handle error however you wish

  cout << "Output file?\n";
  string outputname;
  cin >> outputname;
  ofstream output(outputname.c_str());
  if (!output) return 2;

  while (1) {
    string name;
    int num1, num2;
    input >> name >> num1 >> num2;
    if (!input) break;
    lists(name);
    value(num1, num2);
  }

  return 0;
}
```